# Ant uptodate task does not consider deleted files

Tags: apache-flex, ant

I'm trying to speed up my builds by using the ANT `<updtodate/>` task to check for changes and compile only if necessary. This is for a Flex project. Here is the relevant part of my build.xml:

```
  <target name="framework-clean"
          description="Clean the Framework library">
    <echo>Clean: Deleting dist directory in framework</echo>        
   <delete dir="${flex.framework.dir}/dist"/>
  </target>

  <target name="check-framework-changes">     
      <uptodate property="framework-no-changes" targetfile="${flex.framework.dir}/dist/imanager-framework.swc">
         <srcfiles dir="${flex.framework.dir}/src" />
         <srcfiles dir="${flex.framework.dir}/libs" />         
      </uptodate>             
   </target>

  <target name="framework-compile"            
          depends="check-framework-changes"
          unless="framework-no-changes"
          description="Compile the Framework library">          
    <mkdir dir="${flex.framework.dir}/dist"/>   
    <echo>Compile: Compiling iManager Framework</echo>
    <compc output="${flex.framework.dir}/dist/imanager-framework.swc" 
       debug="${debug}" 
       incremental="${incremental}">            
      <keep-as3-metadata name="Master"/>
      <keep-as3-metadata name="Component"/>
      <keep-as3-metadata name="Key"/>
      <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>
      <source-path path-element="${flex.framework.dir}/src" />
      <library-path dir="${flex.framework.dir}/libs" includes="*.swc" append="true"/>
      <include-sources dir="${flex.framework.dir}/src" includes="*" />          
    </compc>
  </target>
```

The problem:

Suppose I add a file called Foo.as in my project, the script will detect the change and recompile the swc. But if I delete this Foo.as without changing any other files, the script does not compile the project. The change is ignored even though the last modified timestamp of Foo's parent folder is updated.

Is there any way to fix this?

My ANT version is 1.8.4 and I'm using Flex SDK 4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the `check-framework-changes` target to include directories along with files.

```
  <target name="check-framework-changes">     
      <uptodate property="framework-no-changes" targetfile="${flex.framework.dir}/dist/imanager-framework.swc">
        <srcresources>
            <fileset dir="${flex.framework.dir}/src" />
            <fileset dir="${flex.framework.dir}/libs" />
            <dirset dir="${flex.framework.dir}/src" />
            <dirset dir="${flex.framework.dir}/libs" />
        </srcresources>                
      </uptodate>             
   </target>
```

This has solved the problem